# How to detect correct object comparing same object in another array?

Tags: javascript

Here is what I want to do: `original` and `modified` are input arrays, I need to infer the output based on these.

```
    const original = [
                      {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},
                      {label: 'test2', formUid: 204},
                      {label: 'test3', formUid: 258},
                      {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
                      {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
                      {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
                       
                   ];
                   
  const modified = [
                      {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},,
                      {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
                      {label: 'test6', formUid: 1025},
                      {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
  ]
```

I have two arrays, one is `original`, the other one is `modified` (which is a modified copy of `original`).

Considering the above two deleted objects I am going to modify my copy of original array, So I make copy from orginal array delete the two object that I intend to delete, so the output is like this for now

```
   const CopyOforiginal = [
              {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},
              {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
              {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
              {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
               
           ];
```

this is happening in my code you can see It in snippet,

But this the problem now, you can see two duplicated object in original array (I have set the index for example)

```
  original = [
                 [4]:{label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
                 [5]:{label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
                ]
```

and one object in modified array same object as above objects

```
modified = [ 
             [3]:{label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
           ]
```

So How can I compare this ? See if we get the first object from the original array and find modified array have an same object yeah there is a one it found same object from the modified array that finish

Then get second same object from the original array and modify the array to have any matching object with that , there have one but it counted before we can't get again and again same object, so the original array's second duplicated object should be marked as deleted.

This is my intended output:

```
const CopyOforiginal = [
                  {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},,
                  {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
                  {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},

               ];
```

```js
function testFunc(){
      
       const original = [
                          {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},
                          {label: 'test2', formUid: 204},
                          {label: 'test3', formUid: 258},
                          {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
                          {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},

                       ];

      const modified = [
                          {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},,
                          {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
                          {label: 'test6', formUid: 1025},
                          {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
                          {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
      ]
      

    let originalCopy;
  let flag;
  let oForm , oIdx;
  let srcipt = [];
 
   originalCopy = [...original];
   
    original.forEach((originForm, originInx) => {
   
    let res = modified.some(item => item.formUid === originForm.formUid)
   
      if(!res){
srcipt.push(originForm.formUid + " DELETE_FROM " + (originInx+1)); //created the script for deleted form
     
        let res = originalCopy.findIndex(idx => idx.formUid === originForm.formUid); //get the index from copy of the original array
        originalCopy.splice(res, 1); //remove the object
      }
    })
   

    //document.getElementById("originalArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(original);
    //document.getElementById("modifiedArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(modified);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(srcipt);
    document.getElementById("copyArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(originalCopy);
  }
```

```html
<button onClick="testFunc()">Click</button>
originalArray : <p id="originalArray"></p>
modifiedArray : <p id="modifiedArray"></p>
result        : <p id="result"></p>
CopyOf original Array result        : <p id="copyArray"></p>
```

Comment: I can't follow this at all, somewhere you went way off the rails. Please post some input and desired output without all the commentary, e.g. why do you need to compare anything? If you've made a copy, why do you need to mutate the copy? Why not use `Array.prototype.filter`? Unfortunately this doesn't make any sense, please strip it down to input/output.

Comment: First two arrays are (original and Modified) both are input . After all process finally have show the output (CopyOfOriginal)

Comment: This is experiment that I do. That;s why I try to do this. I made a copy because of not damage to original array

Comment: Please see the inputs and see the final output , middle description I have describe what want to happen

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `function` that prunes duplicates, like in the snippet below:

```js
function pruneDuplicates(input) {
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let matches = true;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            for (let key in input[i]) matches &&= (input[i] === input[j]);
        }
        if (!matches) output.push(input[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(pruneDuplicates(
[
    {label: 'test1', formUid: 211},
    {label: 'test4', formUid: 1045},
    {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
    {label: 'test5', formUid: 1096},
]));
```

Comment: my input is not a one array, it must be two arrays. 01. Original array = there contain some specific objects , 02. modified array = modified array  id made from original array and have some extra objects . Comparing both arrays I want to find the objects 

Ex: see modified array have all original array objects. some are not those are deleted one. 
but if original array had two same object and modified array have same one object (check the last part of the my question) we cant match two object with only one object,

Comment: we can do only match one object with another array one object rest of one is get as deleted on

Comment: thing original array have [{1},{1},{1}],  modified array have [{1},{1}] , when you compare according to the indexes 01. original array 0th index and modified array 0th index is matched 02. original array 1th index and modified array 1th index is matched 03. original array 3rd index and modified array ???????th (there dont have an object match) that is consider as deleted one

Comment: @KevinMac746 my understanding is that the problem you have is that in the copy some duplicates remain. So, according to my current understanding of your problem, if we prune the duplicates, then that should resolve the issue. If not, then I need a short and understandable description of what else is needed.

Comment: we want to duplicates I have told you in previous comment using examples also. see this original array have [{1},{1},{1}], modified array have [{1},{1}] , when you compare according to the indexes 01. original array 0th index and modified array 0th index is matched 02. original array 1th index and modified array 1th index is matched 03. original array 3rd index and modified array ???????th (there dont have an object match) that is consider as deleted one

Comment: @KevinMac746 I tried to understand your question and to help, but it turns out that I did not understand it. And I did not understand your comments either. Others did not understood you either. So you need to find a way of clarifying your problem. This is what I was trying to indicate in my previous comment. My current understanding is that your result ended up with duplicates. It is quite possible that I misunderstood the problem, but I do not understand your explanation here in the comment section. I'm happy to help if you provide a short and understandable description of what else is needed

Comment: OK, I explain what is the process, we have two arrays 01. original = [100,200,200], 02. modified = [250,350,200]. So expected result is = [100,200]. Here is the another example 01. original = [100,200,200], 02. modified = [250,350,200,200]. So expected output is = [100]. both are same object no differences, according to first example in first iteration original array 200 going through the modified array and first 200 match with that then we cant match that modified array 200 again because we already matched that.

Comment: In second iteration original array have another 200 we get it and go through the modified array and check you can understand right we don't have 200 for match that actually we have one in modified array but we already have used. I couldn't understand to detect like that . Can you understand that now?

Comment: See the second example I got and output you can understand more

Comment: @KevinMac746 Unfortunately I do not understand why should an input of [100, 200, 200] and [250, 350, 200] result in [100, 200]. My understanding was that we infer the output based on the copy. So, I guess the question is: how and why should the result be [100, 200]? Is it because those are the non-duplicated values of the original? Is it only depending on the original? How is the modified array relevant then?